# filter information by using sed Unix command

Tags: shell

I try to filter the system log by running the sed command
like:

```
error
    info_a1
    info_a2
    info_a3
crit
    info_b 
error
    info_c1 
    info_c2
warn
    info_d 
error
    info_x 
error
    info_p 
info
    info_w 
error
    info_z1 
    info_z2
```

I expect to get all the error messages like：

```
error 
    info_a1
    info_a2
    info_a3 
error
    info_c1 
    info_c2
error
    info_x 
error
    info_p
error
    info_z1 
    info_z2
```

i use

> sed -n "/error/, /[info|warn|crit|]/p"

but it does not work pretty well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
  /^error/ {p=1}
  /^(info|warn|crit)/ {p=0}
  p
'
```

Comment: +1. There's bound to be a way to do this in `sed` as well, but that would probably not be readable.

Comment: @larsmans: Be careful what you [wish for](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050783/filter-information-by-using-sed-unix-command/5052718#5052718).

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to print the error message AND the next line after it, then use

```
cat file_name | grep 'error' -A 1 | grep -v '\-\-'
```

Comment: `cat` with a single argument is wasteful. Just `grep 'error' -A 1 file_name`. Also, `'\-\-'` should be `^--$` for safety.

Comment: WOW! Thank YOU Barun! It works! Could you please explain a little about grep -v '\-\-'. And also if the error information more than on line. grep 'error' -A 1 will not work

Comment: @user380690: `grep -v` gives you all lines except those for which there's a pattern match. If you use just `grep 'error' -A 1`, you will see some '--' lines in between. Use that `grep -v` if you want to skip them. Also, you need to escape the '--' string. Otherwise `grep` will think that you have given a wrong argument to it.

Comment: In general, if you want to print M lines before the matching line, and N lines after the matching one, then use `grep -B M -A N pattern file_name`

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, I entirely agree. Using that way lets me to quickly modify the args to grep without navigating far near the beginning of the line. So, less number of key movements. :)

Comment: Thank you for ur explanation. But grep 'error' -A 1 will not works if the information more than one line.

Comment: I agree. But the line number is not fixed number. Is there any way to extract information without specify the line number, like sed -n '/start/, /stop/p'

Comment: That I think goes beyond the capability of grep or sed. You need a programming language for specifying stronger regular expressions. Otherwise, if you want to have a bit of manual inspection, you can go for this: `grep -v -n -E 'crit|warn|info$' filename`. The output will be like: 
1:error
2:    info_a1
3:    info_a2
4:    info_a3
6:    info_b 
7:error
8:    info_c1 
9:    info_c2
11:    info_d 
12:error
13:    info_x 
14:error
15:    info_p 
17:    info_w 
18:error
19:    info_z1 
20:    info_z2

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to get all lines with "error" in it,

```
grep "error" file
```

if you insist on sed

```
sed -n '/error/p' file
```

or even awk

```
awk '/error/' file
```

or Ruby

```
ruby -ne 'print if /error' file
```

Comment: Kurumi thank you for ur reply, Sorry i think i did not explain the question well. all error and error info are not in the same line. i want to filter all error with error info.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `sed` version:

```
sed -n ':a;/^error/{h;:b;n;${/^[[:blank:]]/{H;x;/^error/{p;q}}};/^[^[:blank:]]/{x;p;x;ba};H;bb}' inputfile
```

Explanation:

```
:a                              # label a
/^error/{                       # if pattern space (patt) begins with "error"
    h                           # copy the line to hold space (hold)
    :b                          # label b
        n                       # read the next line
        ${                      # if it's the last line of input
            /^[[:blank:]]/{     # if it begins with a space, tab, etc.
                H               # append it to hold
                x               # exchange patt and hold
                /^error/{       # if patt begins with "error"
                    p           # print it
                    q           # quit
                }
            }
        }
        /^[^[:blank:]]/{        # if patt starts with a non-blank (a new block of input has started
            x                   # exchange patt and hold
            p                   # print patt
            x                   # exchange patt and hold
            ba                  # branch to label a
        }
        H                       # append patt to hold (save a line of the current block)
        bb                      # branch to b
}
```